.NET Lambda deployed with CDK: how do I unzip the binaries once deployed?
I have a .NET 8 Lambda function that is deployed to AWS via CDK.  The problem is that it gets saved to the bucket as a .zip archive, yet my function is expecting to see the (unzipped) binaries.  As a result, I encounter Error: executable assembly /var/task/My.Lambda.Function.dll or binary /var/task/My.Lambda.Function not found when I execute the function via the gateway invoke URL.
What do I need to change to either get the binaries to unzip when deployed?  (Or, alternatively, allow AWS's Lambda engine to process the zip file directly)?
const functionProps: lambda.FunctionProps = {
    functionName: 'mylambda',
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_8,
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../Infrastructure/build'),
    handler: 'My.Lambda.Function', //Namespace of my .NET assembly
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
};

const codeBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'S3Bucket', {
    removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});

new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployLocation', {
    sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('../Infrastructure/build')],
    destinationBucket: codeBucket,
    destinationKeyPrefix: 'var/task',
    extract: true
});

var lambdaFunc = new lambda.Function(this, "mylambda", functionProps);

const api = new apigateway.LambdaRestApi(this, 'mylambda-api', {
    'handler': lambdaFunc,
    'proxy': true
});


Lambda unzips the deployment artifact automatically, inside the AWS Lambda runtime environment. The code doesn't "run" from S3, that's just where the deployment artifact is stored. I don't think it being in a zip file in S3 is the reason you are getting those errors, unless you have zip files inside of the main deployment artifact zip file. More likely there is some sort of path issue.

Thanks @MarkB.  I looked at the contents of the zip file that gets uploaded to the bucket and it looks right (no zip files inside the main zip).  So then, where would I look in the AWS Console to see that the raw binaries are where they need to be?  And what changes (if any) would I need to make to my CDK file?

The issue you are facing is might be because the AWS Lambda cannot find the specified handler within the zip archive. In .NET Core Lambdas, the handler name typically has the format: assembly::namespace.class-name::method-name e.g:handler: 'MyLambdaFunction::My.Lambda.Function::FunctionHandler'.If you're deploying the function via CDK with code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../Infrastructure/build'), you do not need to separately upload the package using s3deploy.BucketDeployment. AWS CDK's lambda.Code.fromAsset(path) handles the packaging and deployment of the Lambda code.

Make sure that when you build your Lambda function, the output directory should be a zip file that contains the DLLs and all dependencies at the root of the zip.Check the contents of the zip file to ensure that the .dll file and all related dependencies are directly at the root and not inside another nested directory.

The thing is, for my Lambda code, I am using a .NET 8 Core Miminal API.  So there is no method name for me to map my handler property to.  The function that does the work is defined like app.MapGet(url, async (string param1) =>......).  What, then, do I enter for FunctionHandler given that this .NET Core Minimal API style of creating Lambdas doesn't explicitly define one?

@JalpaPanchal my Lambda was built using a .NET Core Minimal API with AddAwsLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi).  Per this article (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/), approximately 3/4 the way to the end of the article, it says "You must deploy as an executable assembly so the function handler string is set to the assembly name only".  This implies that my handler prop, My.Lambda.Function (which is my fully-qualified assembly name) is correct.  So, any suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong?

@MarkB zip files within zip files might be the issue.  I downloaded the code directly from my Lambda's page on the AWS portal.  The downloaded zip is named "mylambda-<unique_identifier>.zip".  Inside that is another zip file simply named "mylambda.zip" (without a unique id appended).  Inside that zip are all my compiled .NET application binaries (including the DLL that CloudWatch said was missing, and I did check the spelling/casing).  But how do I fix this?

What about the zip file you are placing in S3? Is that also a zip inside a zip? That's the only one that matters.

@MarkB thanks - it turns out that the S3 is unneeded since the files are being added directly to the Lambda Runtime.  Everything in that bucket is ignored.  But I am able to temporarily get around the "zip within zip" issue by directly uploading the zip file that contains my app's binaries.  This allows me to run the function without hitting the "assembly not found" error.   I'm suspecting that the "zip within zip" issue is being caused by the Azure pipeline which populates the ../Infrastructure/build that my CDK is referencing.

Yes, it sounds like the pipeline is double zipping your deployment artifacts.

I figured it out.  The Azure pipeline that I was using to deploy the Lambda was zipping the binaries, and my CDK code was zipping them again.
I was able to fix this by adding zipAfterPublish: false to the portion of my pipeline that executes dotnet publish.
But this revealed an additional issue: although the internal folder housing my binaries wasn't zipped, it was still an internal folder nonetheless.  (The Lambda Runtime expects binaries to be at the root of the zip).
I was able to fix this second issue by modifying the code property of my lambda.FunctionProps, adding the path to the internal folder - i.e.,
code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../Infrastructure/build/<lambda_function_binaries_folder_name>').
Now everything works!  Thanks for the helpful advice @JalpaPanchal and @MarkB!
